# Is there a way to enter multiple spaces in a backquoted verbatim in a comment?

Tags: discussion, bug, comments, markdown

This is possible in the quadruple-spaced pre-environment.

```
"Like  here" = S.
%    ^^ two spaces
```

And it also  works here backquoted: `"  "` But see my comment, where it does not work!

Bug or feature? Is there any other way to enter this in a comment?

In [my comment activity list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false?tab=activity&sort=comments) the double spaces shows up! But not in the [real comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973951/replacing-white-spaces-in-prolog/26974021?noredirect=1#comment42483614_26974021).

I am using Firefox 33.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS - with most recent updates.

And here a pic — yes it happened to me! [image: evidence#1]

Comment: Here the same string `"  "` does not work

Comment: Cross-site related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243659/a-double-space-in-a-comment-removes-the-space-immediately-before-the-next-link

Comment: By "backquoted", do you mean "using ['backticks'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20034/differences-between-doublequotes-singlequotes-and-backticks-%C2%B4-%C2%B4-on-comm)"?

Comment: @gunr2171: Yes. See source above!

Comment: Does that string `"  "` work? Apparently yes. Non-breaking spaces are not collapsed. See [my old answer on the Overmeta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104386/164403) for ways to input them.

Comment: @false, well yes. Wasn't your question about entering two consecutive space characters in comments?

Comment: @false, nope, my comment contains non-breaking spaces, code point `U+00A0`. That's why the browser does not collapse them into a single space. I don't know of any other way to reliably input multiple consecutive spaces in comments (well, maybe zero-width joiners between `U+0020` spaces, but I never tried that).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Let my try it :`"  "` - works! Which means there is no verbatim way to write a nbsp. Good to know. Thank you!